# Layout broken on Android 4.0.3

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, webview

I use jQuery mobile and bind data dynamically from PHP JSON services like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/test/test_service.php?user_id=55", function (data) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var i in data) {
        $("<img class='img'/>").attr("src", data[i].catalogue_cover).appendTo("#show-case");
        n++;
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        fadeinfadeout();
    } else if (n == 1) {
        $("<img class='img2'/>").attr("src", data[i].catalogue_cover).appendTo("#show-case");
    }
});

$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/test/test_service.php?user_id=55", function (data) {
    var output = "<span class='item'>";
    for (var i in data) {
        output += "<a href='' onClick='javascript:ShowCatalog(" + data[i].catalogue_id + ")'><img src='" + data[i].catalogue_cover + "' style='border:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);'/></a>";
    }
    output += "</span>";
    $(".group").html(output);
});
```

This is working in Android 4.1 and above, but in Android 4.0.3 devices, it doesn’t show correctly sometimes. I got this:

[image: Screenshot]

I suspect jQuery mobile 1.3.0 does not support Android 4.0.3 well, or there’s a problem with `webview.loadurl`.

Comment: What actual error message are you getting?

Comment: Don't show any json result. All page are show in like above image

Comment: Have you tried a `console.log(output)` when this fails?

Comment: Yes. I tried . But, this error not shows in emulator. In some devices can work ,but most samsung occurs like that.

Comment: My initial suspicion is that there is an error happening in the `for (var i in data) {` loop, causing the `</span>` to not be appended, breaking the format and causing the layout wonkiness.  Hard to say without seeing the response from test_service.php.  Also, the `fadeinfadeout();` method might be causing an error of some sort.  I think we need to see the response form the service.